# Generic React Component Interface whose property types can change based on specific property

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Is there a way to create a React Component with Typescript where certain properties change their types based on the existence/type of a different property?

I am attempting to build a generic react select component, that can either be a multi select or a single select.  It will have a `renderValues` property that will be used to render the selected values.  Ideally, if this component is a multi select, renderValues would have the signature:

```
(selected: T[]) => JSX.Element
```

and if it's a single select it would have the signature

```
(selected: T) => JSX.Element
```

An example of a multi select component would be:

```
<SingleOrMultiSelect
  multiple={true}
  value={['foo','bar']}
  options={['foo','bar','biz','baz']}
  renderValues={(opts: string[])=> opts.join(', ')}
  name={'Example Multi Select'
/>
```

[Here is a Typescript playground showing what I've started trying](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QMIHsC2ADriBOAApS6EbIDeAUMsiHPhAFzIZhSgDmAbibJqYYCQxcefEPwDaAXWEBfBg1CRYiFADU4fOACMANjgLFS4eiIA8AFWQQAHpBAATWgEEoUOAE9bGQEAPgAaNCdXMk9kXgBXCBCAChFmQioaLjpkfHiTcUIzLlQIqBjoAHlCcUkuZLEpbl4BJWQASmQAXhDkACkAZQANADoAUTN2cAiANzgTRK5HFWQAMjRMcyISMjBKagwRdq5B0YmIKbBhZmSMg+zkco8qmokQJoaa6Ra5Du7e07jSa7WbzRbNWT8ZArdboLB4bZWPaZDDHfrDIEXXaqdQISRgZADARmSpQACy+XECMsuy4+kMpi2NOsXWQtxRnR6NmYAHoeQBJGDIOYLFDAWhwEDIAx+fzSjw83BQXKU4BFMW0BIQCIuQgQBAEp7uF61d5xXBxOAAaxQkulvgCIj5EBMWB1zj1Bul3GJKBFiQYKiAA)

It's based heavily off of the `OverideableComponent` from [Material UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/f6b9227ee90c8ceafb00fd4490fca1043a3c4c02/packages/material-ui/src/OverridableComponent.d.ts#L10) but I can't seem to get this working.

Realistically I will just split this logic into a SingleSelect component and a multiselect component, or more likely just require `renderValues` to always expect an array, but I am now curious if there is a clean way to achieve what I had originally sought to do.

Additional Playground link with [the below answer implemented](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QMIHsC2ADriBOAApS6EYA8AKshAB6QgAmGyA8oWOlgB8yAN4AoZMhBx8EAFzIMYKKADmAbgnJqYYCQwL6AbQC6mgL5iwAT0Ipe-TCgC8ordNkKlKkBq0A3OAAbAFd5RWU1ZAAfKRD8ACNoCzFQSFhEFABZEKDdSmo6RhY2Th4+AQhhErIyyrwiEjIwApoGYXFJKFroBz0QA2QACh1B4xMASmRnYQApAGUADQA6AFEgiFlwTUl8XN1CDYVlMJTU8Gh4JGR5tQ3WoqZWWq4HSurnji56gmJSCiobXogk6yG6HF6fH6gxGfDGUxmyAWK3Wm2aO2QezywEOEAA-Ap4EEsGcbHZkAA1OAqOAJDYNP7NB4MJ6lV4VJzCVy3Xz3QFFYSxHLY5nAzRiBD6MA3O4QbhQYW6BlNcDTZAsmpfcqOIRDQj8hRUml0nC-FUtfntBEdLSSgbSkSY-Y4jYAGjBPSgfX07p00PMav1hQxAHoQwBJGDIQKhFDALhwEDIalQODWZMcEO4KBO7G45Dx5AnCDulh2BDS8HsSG6fRF3BFuAAaxQieTUFT1i0YYgxJLT3L0rgillyDEtqlHohUB5qg2VKCwHYathYEM1rckkkwBgQwAhEGaMssQcNhNQVuPWAQlAk4eMMsqzXoauJlpJJYP1oJ-ap9WZ7K4YgDGS4rjo67TDal47vuJ4uhA57vlu3TXref7Pvor5IZ+yCWGI5hAA)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
interface SingleSelectProps {
  multiple: true;
  renderValues: (opts: string[]) => React.ReactNode
}

interface MultiSelectProps {
  multiple: false;
  renderValues: (opts: string) => React.ReactNode
}

type SingleOrMultiSelectProps = SingleSelectProps | MultiSelectProps;
```

Comment: Ah thank you, this is much simpler than the rabbit hole I was going down.  This is not directly related, but something that came up while implementing this:

In order to have the component be able to _know_ which version it is using, I can't use destructured props, I need to reference them like:

`if(props.multiple)...`

I added an example playground link in the original posting.  Any idea if it's possible to get around this?

Comment: Yeah in such a case, Typescript can't infer the type. It just how it works, because now each of the properties are not related anymore. It becomes separate properties.